# Need assistance in troubleshooting Javascript code in an html file for a school project

Tags: javascript, html, masonry

This is my first time posting on stackoverflow, so I apologize if there is any rules or guidelines that I have not followed correctly.

## the problem

I am currently working on a school project where we have to create a website and my website is being built with the masonry (from http://masonry.desandro.com/). I want my images to appear differently every time someone goes to the website, so I wanted to create a system where different images would be loaded. I have put together a code from several sources on the web, but it does not return the correct image (or any for that matter).
     I am still quite new to coding, but what I have tried to do to achieve this is the following:

## the code

```
<img id="image1" class="grid-item grid-item--width2 grid-item--height3" src="http://placehold.it/200x200">
      <script>
        var mydate = new date();
        var mynumber = mydate.getDate();

      document.getElementById("image1").src = "images/" + mynumber +".jpg";
      if(mynumber==33)
      {
          mynumber=1;
      }
      else
      {
          var mynumber=mynumber+1;
      }
      </script>
```

The idea behind this is that it grabs the date, and then uses this date to start grabbing images in my image folder (the images are named 1,2,3,4... this goes on and will be added to, but for testing purposes I have made sure their are over 31). This means the website will load slightly different from day to day. 
However this hasn't worked, and I could not figure out why exactly.

## **Additional Information**

As I am new to much of this I do not know how much information is required to solve this problem so I will now attempt to add as much as I can think of, much of the following may not be needed.

- All my testing was done on chrome
- All my work was done using brackets
- I am using placeholder images for all images to begin with
- Every image loaded on to the page is a placholder image starting with 'image1', 'image2', 'image3'... and so on.
- If I can get this code to work it would be copied under each image and replace them one by one.
- Js file attached:

  ```
  $(document).ready( function() {
      var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item',
          columnWidth: 200
      });

      var $stamp = $grid.find('.stamp');
      var isStamped = false;
      $('.stamp-button').on( 'click', function() {
          // stamp or unstamp element
          if ( isStamped ) {
              $grid.masonry( 'unstamp', $stamp );
          } else {
              $grid.masonry( 'stamp', $stamp );
          }
          // trigger layout
          $grid.masonry('layout');
          // set flag
          isStamped = !isStamped;
      });
  });
  ```

## thank you for your time

Thank you for taking the time to help me with my school project. Any feedback is appreciated, and if you need more information to help please let me know what I can provide you with. Thank you

Comment: What are you seeing in the Console (F12) in Chrome?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't have a solution for you but a heads up on code review.  In your else block you have `var mynumber=mynumber+1;`, you are trying to redeclare your `mynumber` variable within your global scope when it already exists, change that to `mynumber+=1` or `mynumber++`.

Comment: I've also spotted that you try to set your image before validating the value of `mynumber`, I would move `document.getElementById("image1").src = "images/" + mynumber +".jpg";` to after the else block.

Comment: To help us further, could you please post the directory structure of your application, `images/` may not be the correct relative path.  You may need something like `./images/` or `./public/images/` based on your directory hierachy

Comment: I voted to close because "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." Please try and produce a minimal example.

Comment: @Alex even though it makes sense to change it to `mynumber++;` - in that case it would not change anything: it's valid to run `var` multiple times for the same variable in the same scope.

Comment: @zerkms I did say it wouldn't solve his problem, I wanted to offer some code review too

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the masonary.Also I will like to know the image source, Is there any array which is holding the images? or you will get a json response.Just for demo I have put some image in an array .Also not every image has it's extension **.jpg**. On this day of writing that is 8Dec, I have put only 10 images.You can put some empty **' '** before the images just to match the index of the array with image source

```
var tDate = new Date();
var getToday = tDate.getDate();
console.log(imgSource[getToday]);
document.getElementById("image1").src=imgSource[getToday];
```

To see the full code, please visit [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/cj53cu0z/)

Also you have added this part

```
src="http://placehold.it/200x200"
```

Do you need to add the source to image at the location?